# error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader'

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to count records on my saved datas.
Here is my code:

```
    Dim pl_qry As String
    Dim pl_cmd As New Odbc.OdbcCommand
    Dim pl_dr As Odbc.OdbcDataReader

    If txtPurpose.Text = "PERSONAL LOAN" Then
        pl_qry = "select count(purpose) from details where borrower_id = '" & bor_id & "' and purpose = '" & "PERSONAL LOAN" & "'"
        pl_cmd.CommandText = pl_qry
        pl_cmd.Connection = con
        pl_dr = pl_cmd.ExecuteScalar

        pl_dr.Read()
        If Not pl_dr.IsDBNull(0) Then
            MsgBox(pl_dr.GetString(0))
        End If
    End If
```

I got my error in this line

```
    pl_dr = pl_cmd.ExecuteScalar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have check the [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) method, you will notice it will return the first column of the first row of your SQL.

Problem is you have assigned the result to 'OdbcDataReader`

```
Dim pl_dr As Odbc.OdbcDataReader
```

but maybe you can just get the result directly:

```
Int64 result = Convert.ToInt64(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
```